# Is it possible to use eval to exit a function?

Tags: javascript, eval

I have a code similar to this.

```js
function foo(script) {
  console.log(1);
  
  if(script) {
    eval(script);
  }
  
  console.log(2);
}

foo(/* Some expression */);

console.log(3);
```

I want it to print `1` and `3` but skip `2`.

---

I tried

```js
foo('return');
```

It doesn't work.

---

Also I tried

```js
foo('throw new Error()')
```

But it skips `3` as well.

---

So is it possible to exit that function via `eval`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `throw new Error()` expression will work, but you will need to wrap `eval(script)` and all your subsequent logic inside  a try/catch block:

```js
function foo(script) {
  console.log(1);
  
  try {
    if (script) {
      eval(script);
    }
    
    console.log(2);
  } catch(e) { }
}

foo('throw new Error()');

console.log(3);
```

Comment: This `foo` function belongs to an old API. I was thinking if it's possible to only manipulate the `script` input to achieve that. If it's not, I have to make a change of that API, which is not ideal :( But thanks for the answer, I think I can wrap the `foo()` invoking part in `try` block instead, it will be clearer :)